# how to display images as ("Eval") in slider

Tags: sql, asp.net, arrays, image, for-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqpeX.png)

SqlConnection cnn = klas.baglan();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" Select * from Images where ID="+ID, cnn);

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


while (dr.Read())
{

    Image[] imageArray = new Image[dr.FieldCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.Length; i++)
    {
        imageArray[i] = new Image();


        imageArray[i].ImageUrl = "~/Images/800/" + dr[2].ToString();
        //Response.Write(imageArray[i].ImageUrl);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(imageArray[i]);

    }

}
```

I did an array for the images which comes from dataBase also I tried to display on the Repeater but I am not sure code that is what  I've written, should I use the Image item by using Repeater for comes Images. I showed it below

Comment: Please edit the markup into the question, it is readable in comments

Comment: My english is not enough please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't add the ImageUrl to the image object.

Try this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="ssds" ImageUrl='<% Eval("resim")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

'/' Uygulamasında Sunucu Hatası.

Ayrıştırıcı Hatası

Açıklama: Bu isteği yerine getirmek için gereken bir kaynağın ayrıştırılması sırasında hata oluştu. Lütfen aşağıdaki özel ayrıştırma hatası ayrıntılarını gözden geçirin ve kaynak kodunuzu uygun biçimde değiştirin.

Ayrıştırıcı Hata İletisi: Sunucu etiketi biçimi uygun değil.

Comment: When I write code that you adviced,but program gives an error,

Comment: May you try this? `<asp:Image runat="server" ID="ssds" ImageUrl='<% Eval("images")%>' />`